# Ckeditor - shared toolbar does not work

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the shared spaces plugin with Ckeditor to load a shared toolbar for multiple ckeditors but it still loads individual toolbar for all editors.

Here is a fiddle with the code that I am using: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lrcup3L/

HTML:

```
<div id="topSpace"></div>
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<textarea id="editor2" name="editor2"></textarea>
<div id="bottomSpace"></div>

JS:
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',{
   sharedSpaces: {
     top: 'topSpace',
     bottom: 'bottomSpace'
   } 
 })
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor2',{
   sharedSpaces: {
     top: 'topSpace',
     bottom: 'bottomSpace'
   }
 })
```

Need help with the same!

Answer (score 1):

[Shared Space](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) is an optional plugin that is not included in the Standard preset. You should add it to your build first and/or enable with [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins).

Check the source code of the [Shared Toolbar and Bottom Bar](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html) SDK sample - just scroll down to the "Get Sample Source Code" to see a working sample for classic and inline editors.